# What's the quickest way to pull up Vim's quickref page?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

What is the simple key combination in Vim to bring up the quickref page, or at least a page that is functionally similar i.e. it contains a list of commands and their key bindings?

After manhandling Google for 15 minutes, I can't find anything shorter than **:h quickref**.

Comment: Learn to type faster? :-) Or `:h q<up>` if it's already in your command-line history.

Comment: How long will it take you to save the number of keystrokes you typed into Google? 8-)}

Comment: I don't have time to learn to type faster :-) This is really just a thing that niggles me. I know it is there. I used to use it a lot but I haven't been using Vim for a while and have forgotten how to display it. Oh puny human mind, why do you mock me?

Comment: You could leave it open in another tab if you are using it a lot. Otherwise just map it to a key as in the answer below.

Comment: Ok. I am going to delete this question because I've remembered how you access this page, which isn't in vim at all but in less, which has some similar key bindings to vim.

Comment: Hmm. Can't delete an answered question. Oh well. I will check the answer given for correctness against the question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the same as `:help quickref` but

```
:viu[sage]
```

opens `:help visual-index` and

```
:exu[sage]
```

opens `:help ex-cmd-index`.

Comment: I've marked this as correct because it answers the question, even though I was in fact thinking of another program.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do it, but you could remap a key.

I personally think the `F1` key for the default help page is useless to me. Maybe you are in the same boat and could remap it to the quickref.

```
noremap <F1> :h quickref<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is a better way. Or did I dream it?

Comment: @SimonHoare I can't find anything that isn't a remap or just typing it in manually

Comment: I guess you could do `:h Con`, but this mapping will really be the fastest.